How do I create a continuous listening speech to text React Component?
I have a few requirements that I am not achieving with my code:
Requirements

Continuous listening when the thumb or mouse is down
To stop listening only when the thumb or mouse goes up

Problem
When I pause to think about what I will say next, with my mouse or thumb still down, it stops listening. If I re-start listening when it ends, the microphone noise Chrome makes on mobile sounds like it stops and immediately starts.
Sample code:
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

const ListeningComponent = () => {
  const [listening, setListening] = useState(false);
  const [transcript, setTranscript] = useState("");
  const [interimTranscript, setInterimTranscript] = useState("");
  const recognitionRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window !== "undefined" && "webkitSpeechRecognition" in window) {
      const recognition = new window.webkitSpeechRecognition();
      recognition.continuous = true;
      recognition.interimResults = true;
      recognition.lang = "en-US";

      recognition.onresult = (event) => {
        let finalTranscript = "";
        let interim = "";
        for (let i = event.resultIndex; i < event.results.length; ++i) {
          if (event.results[i].isFinal) {
            finalTranscript += event.results[i][0].transcript;
          } else {
            interim += event.results[i][0].transcript;
          }
        }
        setTranscript((transcript) => transcript + finalTranscript);
        setInterimTranscript(interim);
      };

      recognition.onend = () => {
        if (listening) recognition.start();
      };

      recognitionRef.current = recognition;
    }
  }, []);

  const handleStartListening = () => {
    setListening(true);
    recognitionRef.current?.start();
  };

  const handleStopListening = () => {
    setListening(false);
    recognitionRef.current?.stop();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={handleStartListening} disabled={listening}>
          Start Listening
        </button>
        <button onClick={handleStopListening} disabled={!listening}>
          Stop Listening
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        {listening ? <p>Listening... Please speak.</p> : <p>Not listening.</p>}
        <p>Transcript: {transcript}</p>
        {interimTranscript && <p>Interim: {interimTranscript}</p>}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ListeningComponent;

